# create random questions using a txt file

Tags: python

I can not solve a problem in python.
  the code opens a text file where are the questions.
how to put the correct answer for each question?

cod:

```
import random
file = open('/home/jonny/questions.txt', 'r')
text = file.read()
separator = '*'
questions = text.split(separator)
print random.choice(questions)
```

attempt:

```
resp=raw_input('answer: ')
for question[0] in questions:
if resp=='a':
print 'gratzz'
```

txt:

```
*how are you?
a) well
b) badly
c) do not know
*What are your plans for today
a) nothing
b) something
c) do not know
```

Comment: What does questions.txt contain?

Comment: txt:

*how are you?
a) well
b) badly
c) do not know
*What are your plans for today
a) nothing
b) something
c) do not know

Comment: @JBernardo: OP does separate question/answers w/ newlines, the question was not formatted correctly. I've submitted an edit to his question to reflect that.

Comment: most would not be the easiest solution . if I add 1000 to txt questions would have to define 1000 separators.
My problem is that I can not set the correct answer for each question in txt already tried using the loop  for and nothing

Comment: What denotes that something is the correct answer?

Comment: Suppose I want the first question "a" and the second is "b." How should I do?

Comment: Are you free to define whatever text format you want? If so, there are better ways to do this.

Comment: what would be the best way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try storing your data in a standard structured format such as JSON. [A library for parsing JSON is included with Python](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html).

Create a file called `questions.json` containing:

```
{
  "What are your plans for today?": {
    "answers": ["nothing", "something", "do not know"],
    "correct_answer": 2
  },
  "how are you?": {
    "answers": ["well", "badly", "do not know"],
    "correct_answer": 1
  }
}
```

Then you can parse it and ask the user a random question like this:

```
import json
import random

# read data from JSON file
questions = json.load(open("questions.json"))

# pick a random question
question = random.choice(questions.keys())

# get the list of possible answers and correct answer for this question
answers = questions[question]['answers']
correct_answer = questions[question]['correct_answer']

# display question and list of possible answers    
print question
for n, answer in enumerate(answers):
    print "%d) %s" % (n + 1, answer)

# ask user for answer and check if it's the correct answer for this question
resp = raw_input('answer: ')
if resp == str(correct_answer):
    print "correct!"
else:   
    print "sorry, the correct answer was %s" % correct_answer
```

Example output:

```
What are your plans for today?
1) nothing
2) something
3) do not know
answer: 3
sorry, the correct answer was 2
```

Comment: I am very grateful for the tip.
  Can you comment the code for me because I do not know some of them

Comment: @Jonny - I have added some comments.

Comment: the code is not working.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 6, in <module>
    questions = json.load(open("question.json"))
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'questions.json'


I already created the file question.json

Comment: @Jonny - The file should be called questions.json, not question.json.

Comment: I still have a problem. The code does not generate a new question when the answer is correct.